# Download a complete website

Tags: html, wget

I need to download a website with css files included. For example wget -r http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ to look up it offline. I have tried to make it with wget but I coudn't (only download *.html). Is there any way to do it with wget?

Inside the downloaded html, "stylesheet" points to the online page not local file .css

```
<link href="http://www.djangoproject.com/m/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

How can I change it in all pages and css files.

Thanks for all,

Comment: There's no easy way. check out a few pages and understand the pattern of how they link to the css files, then grep it. If it didn't download the css files at all, grep all the html files to extract the style sheet links and pipe those to wget.

Comment: This is not really a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a couple more switches, at least:

```
--page-requisites # get all the elements that compose the page (images, CSS and so on)
--convert-links # convert links so that they work locally, off-line
```

See the man page for any others you may require...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac or iPhone, I've had good experience with this app: http://www.sitesucker.us/home.html

Comment: I have try it before, but I obtain the same result! Not local .css files.